# jqMath: how to change the color of an expression?

Tags: css, jqmath

I have this DOM class which I add to a jqMath expression to change the color of part of an equation which I've written using jqmath and the corresponding CSS:

```
.myclass {
  color: blue;
}
```

The thing is the color usually changes as expected but this is not the case if I have for example a division in the equation like this: `$d/\dx[x^2]$`. In this case the color isn't applied to the division (neither to numerator nor to denominator). As far as I know to add a class in jqmath I have to use this `\cl "myclass"` command.

**Edit:**
This is my css:

```
#myid {
  align-text: left;
}
.myclass {
  color: blue;
}
.myclass:active {
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

and html:

```
<body>
  <div>
    <p id='myid' >$\cl 'myclass' {d/\dx[x]}$</p>
    <br>
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just in case anybody have the same problem i solved it by adding a * next to the class in css

```
.myclass *{
color:blue ;
}
```

Comment: Since this solved your issue, you should accept your own answer: this will indicate that this is actually a solution.

Answer (score 1):

Use `$\cl"myclass" {d/\dx [x^2]}$`, i.e. put `{}` around the expression to group it into a single item.

You might like `$\cl"myclass" {d/{\it \dx} [x^2]}$` even better (I think it looks more standard).

Comment: from this example $\cl "myclass" {d/\dx [x^2]}$ the color change apply only to [x^2] while the division and anything above it or below it(numerator or denominator)  don't change which is my problem

Comment: Do you have a test page or fiddle for this that I could view? I think you must have some other style rules with higher specificity or something, because the whole expression changed color for me.

Comment: i added the css and html ,i am testing it on android webview. anyway it works fine if i added a star next to the class in the css